# Trying to UPDATE 2 tables using MYSql Failing

Tags: asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `individual_Address_update`(

IN oIndividualID       int(11),
IN oParentID         int(11),
IN oFarmName         varchar(45),
IN oFirstName        varchar(45),
IN oLastName         varchar(45),
IN oMiddleName       varchar(45),
IN oRoleTypeID       int(11),
IN oPhone            varchar(45),
IN oPhoneExtention   varchar(45),
IN oMobilPhone       varchar(45),
IN oFax              varchar(45),
IN oEmail            varchar(45),
IN oAddress1         varchar(45),
IN oAddress2         varchar(45), 
IN oCity             varchar(45), 
IN oState            varchar(45), 
IN oZip              varchar(45),
IN oCountry          varchar(45) 
)
BEGIN
    Update individual i
    left join address a
    on a.individualID =  i.individualID 
    set 
        i.individualID = oIndividualID, 
        i.ParentID = oParentID,
        i.FarmName = oFarmName, 
        i.FirstName = oFirstName,
        i.LastName = oLastName,
        i.MiddleName = oMiddleName,
        i.RoleTypeID = oRoleTypeID,
        i.Phone = oPhone, 
        i.PhoneExtention = oPhoneExtention,
        i.MobilPhone = oMobilPhone,
        i.Fax = oFax, 
        i.Email = oEmail,
        a.individualID = oIndividualID,
        a.Address1 = oAddress1,
        a.Address2 = oAddress2,
        a.City = oCity,
        a.State = oState,
        a.Zip = oZip,
        a.Country = oCountry
        Where i.individualID = a.individualID;
END
```

I bring this into SqlDataSource For my FormView and when I try to Update the database and 2 tables, I get this error: Parameter 'oIndividualID' not found in the collection.
What am I doing wrong? I just need to Update 2 tables using a stored procedure in MySql and a FormView in Asp.net Page.

Comment: (unrelated to the question:) Using `Where i.individualID = a.individualID`, means you are actually doing an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Posting the asp.net code you are using to call the stored procedure would be useful; also note that you don't appear to be filtering on individualID *anywhere* in your query; this will update every row that the join condition satisfies, and not just for the individual user (unless you intend this). If you don't, then you should change your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the parameters, make sure you use the ?

E.g.:
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?oIndividualID", 3);

Comment: Thanks. This is a stored procedure. I'm not calling this in code behind or anything.

Comment: Yes, but the stored procedures has parameters. Check if SqlDataSource to see if the parameters are set correctly. By the way, if you are using MySQL database, you should have MySqlDataSource instead, right?

Comment: I don't thin Asp.Net provides a MySqlDataSource in my toolbox. Unless this is something new?

Comment: I am using MySql datasource. But I am using the SqlDataSource from my toolbox to get stored procs from database. It works fine with all my procs. It's this updating 2 tables that is causing problems.